# Setting source to a azure media player

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint, azure-media-services

I have a azure media player embedded in my SharePoint page.
The source to the file to be played is set dynamically through a script file.Th source files can be of wmv/mp4/mpg formats and retrived from a sharepoint video portal.

However the source is not being set or it throws some error.
Please find the code below.

HTML:

```
<video id="vid1" class="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin video-responsive" autoplay controls width="100%" height="100%" poster="poster.jpg">

    <p class="amp-no-js">
        To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that supports HTML5 video
    </p>
</video>
```

JS:

```
var myPlayer = amp('vid1', { /* Options */
                                 "nativeControlsForTouch": false,
                                 autoplay: false,
                                 controls: true,
                                  width: "640",
                                  height: "400",
                                 poster: ""
                                 }, function() {
                                          console.log('Good to go!');
                                         // add an event listener
                                            this.addEventListener('ended',         function() {
                                            console.log('Finished!');
                                                        });
                                                }
                                );

myPlayer.src([{ 

    "src": "<<URL to the source file in video portal>>", 
    "type":  "type": "application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml"
}]);
```

Comment: HTML code in page: 

<video id="vid1" class="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin video-responsive" autoplay controls width="100%" height="100%" poster="poster.jpg">
    
    <p class="amp-no-js">
        To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that supports HTML5 video
    </p>
</video>

Answer (score 3):

The mime type you're using in your given code implies that you're trying to set a smoothstreaming source (application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml) 
if you are setting the source as an MP4 you should use the mime type video/mp4

```
myPlayer.src([{ src: "YOUR_SOURCE.mp4", type: "video/mp4" }]);
```

you can check out [this sample](http://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/samples/dynamic_progressiveVideo.html) which plays back progressive MP4 content from the Azure Media Player [samples page](http://aka.ms/ampsamples)

Also, I'm not sure if this was a typo or not but you have `"type":` included in your code twice.

Comment: Thanks Sraje.
The source file can be of type wmv/mp4/mpg and hence setting mime type as video/mp4 will not fix it.
But I was able to make the player work by adding the protectioninfo.

Comment: This code fixed it.
myPlayer.src([{ 
 
        "src": source,  //url to the source
         "type": "application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml",
         "protectionInfo": [{ 
             "type": "AES",
               "authenticationToken":data.value,
             "disableUrlRewriter": true
                           }] }, ]
      );

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to https://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/.

Authentication token of a sharepoint videoportal file can be retreived using GetStreamingKeyAccessToken rest service.